# React botstrap date picker - customization

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to customize the `react-bootstrap-daterangepicker` in the following way:

I want to use different background colors for state when the dates in range are selected and when the user is only hovering to select the dates.

On the screenshot shown below, you can see that wen I hover over the dates, the selected range days are light blue color.

[image]

Same background color is when I actually select the desired range, only difference is the background color of the last day in range:

[image]

Is there a way to make different background collor for those 2 states above?
The problem is that in both states the days that are in range have same classes:

```
.in-range
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Watching this [example](https://projects.skratchdot.com/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/?knob-label=click%20to%20open&selectedKind=DateRangePicker&selectedStory=simple&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=1&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel) I see class `.start-date`for first day in range and `.end-date` for last day in range. May you can try manipulating these classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize background color of start & end dates like so:

```
/* Start Date */
.daterangepicker td.start-date,
.daterangepicker td.start-date.active {
    background-color: #dc3545;
}

/* End Date */
.daterangepicker td.end-date,
.daterangepicker td.end-date.active {
    background-color: #dc3545;
}

/* Today (Initial Color) */
.daterangepicker td.today.active {
    background-color: #28a745;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://0bhlz.csb.app) and the [source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker-customization-0bhlz).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the demo code, but my question is a bit defferetn, I want to set two different background collors for days in range when user selects(the first day is picked and user hovers on the end date but not click on it) and different background for days when the range is selected.